# Configuring Docker to create a container for an Angular App

Tags: c#, angular, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I am trying to get a default Angular App working inside a Docker container.  Here are the steps I have followed:

1) Open Visual Studio 2017 and select: File/New/Project.

2) Select ASP.NET Core Web Application.  Click OK.

3) Select .NET Core 2.2 and Angular.  I notice that 'Enable Docker Support' is greyed out.  Not sure why.  Tried the first three steps in Visual Studio 2019 and it is the same.  Untick Configure for HTTPS.  Click OK.

4) Right click on the project and select Add/Container Orchestration Support.  Select the Container Orchestration as Docker Compose and the target OS as Linux.

5) Rebuild the app

When I launch the app I see this:

[image]

My Docker File looks like this:

```
    FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.2-aspnetcore-runtime AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80

FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.2-sdk AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["Web/WebSPA/WebSPA.csproj", "Web/WebSPA/"]
RUN dotnet restore "Web/WebSPA/WebSPA.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/Web/WebSPA"
RUN dotnet build "WebSPA.csproj" -c Release -o /app

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "WebSPA.csproj" -c Release -o /app

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "WebSPA.dll"]
```

I saw another question, which suggested changing the DockerFile to something like this:

```
ARG NODE_IMAGE=node:8.11
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:2.2 AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80

FROM ${NODE_IMAGE} as node-build
WORKDIR /web
COPY src/Web/WebSPA .
RUN npm install
RUN npm run build:prod

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:2.2 AS build
WORKDIR /src

COPY scripts scripts/

COPY src/Web/*/*.csproj /src/csproj-files/

COPY . .
COPY --from=node-build /web/wwwroot /src/src/Web/WebSPA/wwwroot/
WORKDIR /src/src/Web/WebSPA
RUN dotnet publish -c Release -o /app

FROM build AS publish

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "WebSPA.dll"]
```

However, it made no difference.

Comment: you must have docker installed on your machine, also - if your target is only to RUN docker container with angular - you dont need visual studio at all

Comment: @happyZZR1400, I have Docker installed.  The app would not even run if I did not have Docker installed.

Comment: are you able to run some simple container like "docker run hello-world"?

Comment: @happyZZR1400, yes I am.  I also have Docker working with an MVC app.  Is there anything wrong with my dockerfile?

Comment: as far as i can see - you trying to build image. and not angular, but dot-net MVC, am i right?

Comment: @happyZZR1400, I think I follow what you are saying and the answer is, yes.

Comment: as far as i know- to build some image - you only need to run "docker build ." command, and docker suppose to do all the work (i mean - that is that visual studio running behind the scenes)

Comment: @happyZZR1400, where do you run docker build? I am trying to run this from VS 2017.

Comment: open cmd and navigate to your current directory (at windows you can write "cmd" at folder url bar and terminal window will appear)

Comment: what is the current location? The location of the solution file?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/205238/discussion-between-happyzzr1400-and-w0051977).